# Многоуровневое меню JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, dropdown

Есть многоуровневое меню, второе меню открывается по клику на `menu-first --clickable` пункт 2.
Проблема в том, что когда происходит клик  на `menu-second --clickable`, открывается третье меню, но первое закрывается((
Второе и третье меню располагаются горизонтально друг за другом)

Подайте идею как исправить

```js
$(function() {
  $('.--clickable').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('--active');
  });
});
```

```css
li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li>ul.--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu-first">
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><a href="">Пункт 2</a>
    <ul class="menu-second">
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 2</a></li>
      <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><a href="">Ссылка 3</a>

        <ul class="menu-third">
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 3</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 4</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `click` у вас обрабатывал весь `ul` и любой клик внутри по любому элементу.

Сейчас метод срабатывает только при клике по ссылке внутри `.--clickable`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.--clickable>a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active');
  });
});
```

```css
li>ul {
  display: none;
}

li>ul.--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu-first">
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><a href="">Пункт 2</a>
    <ul class="menu-second">
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 2</a></li>
      <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><a href="">Ссылка 3</a>

        <ul class="menu-third">
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 1</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 2</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 3</a></li>
          <li class="menu-third__link"><a href="">Товар 4</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="menu-second__link"><a href="">Ссылка 4</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li class="menu-first__link"><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
</ul>
```